# Bug in math rendering of question title after canceling edit

Tags: bug, status-completed

On [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53504/if-a-n2-converges-to-0-then-a-n-converges-to-0), if I go to edit my answer and then click "cancel" beside the submit button, the title of the question changes to

"If (a2n)(a_n^2) converges to 00, then (an)(a_n) converges to 00"

However, the math in the question itself still renders correctly.

I am using Firefox 5.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8.

---

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Reproduced even by clicking "Edit" on the question, and then "Cancel". Firefox 5.0-1 on Arch Linux 64bit.

Comment: @Theo: thanks for the image.

Comment: This "doubling up" seems to happen in all questions that contain math in the title on cancelling an edit.

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7 64-bit, Chrome 12.0.742.122.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the title wasn't reset to the correct LaTeX source when cancelling. This is fixed in the next build of the site.

Comment: Can't reproduce it at the moment, so the next build must have gone live.

Comment: It did indeed, a few minutes ago.